# Use instance method in click handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Todo class that has a delete method. I would like to use the delete method as an @click handler:

```
<div v-for="todo in todos">
    <v-btn @click="todo.delete">Delete</v-btn>
</div>
```

Unfortunately this gives me:

```
Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined
```

Comment: Can you provide your `class` code? It seems like `Vue` gets an undefined instead of your method

Comment: are you sure the method exists? what do you see if you console.log todos in the created hook?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple codepen example that shows the core concept working: https://codepen.io/nickforddesign/pen/YYwgKx

The issue is that the items in your todos array don't have the method.

```
<div class="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      {{ todo }}
      <button @click="todo.delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the js

```
new Vue({
  el: '.app',
  data() {
    return {
      todos: [{
        name: '1',
        delete() {
          alert(`delete`)
        }
      },{
        name: '2',
        delete() {
          alert(`delete`)
        }
      }]
    }
  }
})
```